# Phoenix sql query not working with large dataset

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix, bigdata

I have 5 millions records in `hbase` and tried to find total count of records then I am getting following error using phoenix command line.

```
Error: org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixIOException: Failed to get result within timeout, timeout=60000ms (state=08000,code=101)
org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixIOException: org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixIOException: Failed to get result within timeout, timeout=60000ms
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.ServerUtil.parseServerException(ServerUtil.java:111)
    at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.BaseResultIterators.getIterators(BaseResultIterators.java:771)
    at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.BaseResultIterators.getIterators(BaseResultIterators.java:714)
    at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.ConcatResultIterator.getIterators(ConcatResultIterator.java:50)
    at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.ConcatResultIterator.currentIterator(ConcatResultIterator.java:97)
    at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.ConcatResultIterator.next(ConcatResultIterator.java:117)
    at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.BaseGroupedAggregatingResultIterator.next(BaseGroupedAggregatingResultIterator.java:64)
    at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.UngroupedAggregatingResultIterator.next(UngroupedAggregatingResultIterator.java:39)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixResultSet.next(PhoenixResultSet.java:778)
    at sqlline.BufferedRows.<init>(BufferedRows.java:37)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.print(SqlLine.java:1650)
    at sqlline.Commands.execute(Commands.java:833)
    at sqlline.Commands.sql(Commands.java:732)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:808)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:681)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:398)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:292)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixIOException: Failed to get result within timeout, timeout=60000ms
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206)
    at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.BaseResultIterators.getIterators(BaseResultIterators.java:766)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixIOException: Failed to get result within timeout, timeout=60000ms
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.ServerUtil.parseServerException(ServerUtil.java:111)
    at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.TableResultIterator.initScanner(TableResultIterator.java:203)
    at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.ParallelIterators$1.call(ParallelIterators.java:108)
    at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.ParallelIterators$1.call(ParallelIterators.java:103)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.phoenix.job.JobManager$InstrumentedJobFutureTask.run(JobManager.java:183)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to get result within timeout, timeout=60000ms
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.call(ClientScanner.java:327)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.nextScanner(ClientScanner.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.initializeScannerInConstruction(ClientScanner.java:167)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.<init>(ClientScanner.java:162)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getScanner(HTable.java:794)
    at org.apache.phoenix.iterate.TableResultIterator.initScanner(TableResultIterator.java:199)
```

Please look into this as I am not able to solve this problem. As I have changed the configration of Hbase as per this side refrence but it is still not working.

https://community.hortonworks.com/content/supportkb/49037/phoenix-sqlline-query-on-larger-data-set-fails-wit.html

I have changed in following path  /etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml . Do I need to copy this at any where in phoenix configration as I am not understanding this one. Could you help me for this.

Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Do you have any joins in the query? I had this happen and used the query hints to optimize.  The other bit is have you done any trials with the sqlline-thin.py vs sqline.py they emulate using the thick client and the query server

Answer (score 2):

Its late to answer but i had the same issue which i solved by setting maxSessionTimeout to a larger value in zoo.cfg(can be done through ambari in hdp). The default is 60000ms or one minute after which zookeeper closes the session that it opened for the query.

Answer (score 0):

you can increase these params to solved:

1. phoenix.query.timeoutMs
2. hbase.regionserver.lease.period
3. hbase.rpc.timeout
4. hbase.client.scanner.timeout.period